# Directory walk call method when directory is reached

Tags: ruby, search, methods, directory, directory-walk

Trying to write a script that will search through a directory and sub-directories for specific files. I would like to do know how a certain directory or directories come up to call a method.

this is what I have tried and failed:

```
def display_directory(path)
list = Dir[path+'/*'] 
return if list.length == 0

list.each do |f|     

  if File.directory? f #is it a directory?
    if File.directory?('config')
      puts "this is the config folder"
    end
    printf "%-50s %s\n", f, "is a directory:".upcase.rjust(25)
  else
    printf "%-50s %s\n", f, "is not a directory:".upcase.rjust(25)
  end
 end
end


start = File.join("**")
puts "Processing directory\n\n".upcase.center(30)
display_directory start
```

this is what I want to happen.

```
        app
app/controllers
app/helpers
app/mailers
app/models
app/models/bugzilla
app/models/security
app/views
app/views/auth
app/views/calendar
app/views/layouts
app/views/step
app/views/step_mailer
app/views/suggestion
app/views/suggestion_mailer
app/views/task
app/views/user
bin
--------------------------------------
config <----------(call method foo)
config/environments
config/initializers
config/locales
--------------------------------------
db
db/bugzilla
db/migrate
db/security
lib
lib/tasks
log
public
public/images
public/javascripts
public/stylesheets
script
script/performance
script/process
--------------------------
test <---------(call method foobar)
test/fixtures
test/fixtures/mailer
test/functional
test/integration
test/performance
test/unit
--------------------------
vendor
vendor/plugins
```

Comment: why it failed? Error? What happened? What is the output of your script? What ruby version?

Comment: It prints out "this is the config folder" but its the wrong folder. `this is the config folder tmp/cache/B27/910`  is true its a directory just not the one im looking for.  my if statement is off.

Comment: I didn't understand your wording. Can you please re-formulate your question with an exact expectations?

Comment: I am working on a directory crawl.  when it gets to a certain directory I want it to call a method, then finish the crawl possibly execute another method when it finds another desired directory.

Answer (score 0):

Instead

```
if File.directory?('config')
```

Try

```
if f.path.include?('config')
```

but this will work for every directory that have config on the name. You can put a larger substring to make a better match.

Also, it is very idiomatic in ruby use `do..end` for multiline blocks and `{..}` for single line.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way.  this works pretty well.  I've added a method to show all the files in mentioned directory when reached.

```
def special_dir(path)
  puts "------------------------------------"
  sp_path = Dir.glob(File.join(path,"*","**"))
  sp_path.each do |cf|
    puts "\t" + cf
  end
end

def walk(path)
  list = Dir[path+'/*'].reject{ |r| r['doc'] || r['tmp']}
    list.each do |x|
      path = File.join(path, x)
      if File.directory?(x)
        if x =~ /config/ or x =~ /test/  
          special_dir(x)
        else 
          puts "#{x}"
          walk(path)
        end
      else
        #puts x
      end
    end
  end

  start = File.join("**")

  walk start
```